# php код, как заблокировать отправку сообщения при пустом атрибуте

Tags: php

Есть код, который отвечает за отправку уведомлений о переходе на страницу, отправляя  результат в телеграм чат для администрации. Но вместе с реальными переходами оно отправляет много пустых спам смс.
Нужно сделать так чтобы  если атрибут $check был пустым- смс не отправлялось, а блокировалось.

```
<?
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$check = $_GET["check"];
$description = $_GET["description"];
$order_id = $_GET["order_id"];

include "config.php";

date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Moscow");

  $date = date("d-m-Y H:i");
  


  $messagewk = "<b>Переход на оформление</b> \n 1. Продукт: ".$_GET["check"]." \n 2. IP: ".$ip." ".$country_code." ".$city_name_ru." \n 3. Описание: ".$_GET["description"]."\n 4. Дата: ".$date."";
sendTelwk($messagewk);

 function sendTelwk($messagewk){
      $id = "-??????????????????"; 
      $tokken = "?????????????????";
      $filename = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$tokken."/sendMessage?chat_id=".$id."&text=".urlencode($messagewk)."&parse_mode=html";
      file_get_contents($filename); 
  }
```

Comment: http://php.net/if

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!empty($check)) {
    sendTelwk($messagewk);
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]